# Resize svg image

Tags: html, css, svg, image-resizing

I recently downloaded a linkedin svg image (website: https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/linkedin_185964?term=linkedin%20logo&page=1&position=15) i have tried endlessly to resize to fit a 16x16 pixel but i can't make it work. I even tried multiple resources online but no success. This is the code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 512.002 512.002" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512.002 512.002;" xml:space="preserve">
<circle style="fill:#4376B1;" cx="256.001" cy="256" r="256"/>
<path style="fill:#336699;" d="M511.016,233.634L394.729,117.198c-71.035,9.237-145.27,7.859-216.305,9.511
 c-29.306,0-58.613,13.791-53.441,46.545c10.343,65.508,15.515,129.293,3.448,196.525c-1.9,8.545-5.897,17.089-11.117,25.059
 L233.48,511.005c7.421,0.646,14.929,0.996,22.519,0.996c141.384,0,256-114.616,256-256
 C512.001,248.461,511.656,241.005,511.016,233.634z"/>
<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M376.023,109.468H135.979c-14.643,0-26.51,11.867-26.51,26.51V376.02
 c0,14.639,11.867,26.51,26.51,26.51h240.042c14.639,0,26.51-11.871,26.51-26.51V135.978
 C402.533,121.335,390.662,109.468,376.023,109.468L376.023,109.468z M200.155,362.517c0,4.263-3.453,7.716-7.716,7.716h-32.837
 c-4.263,0-7.716-3.455-7.716-7.716V224.856c0-4.263,3.455-7.716,7.716-7.716h32.839c4.263,0,7.716,3.455,7.716,7.716v137.661
 H200.155z M176.02,204.162c-17.23,0-31.196-13.969-31.196-31.201c0-17.229,13.965-31.196,31.196-31.196
 c17.232,0,31.198,13.969,31.198,31.196C207.218,190.195,193.251,204.162,176.02,204.162L176.02,204.162z M371.773,363.139
 c0,3.918-3.175,7.096-7.09,7.096h-35.242c-3.915,0-7.092-3.177-7.092-7.096v-64.574c0-9.63,2.826-42.21-25.172-42.21
 c-21.719,0-26.124,22.3-27.008,32.304v74.478c0,3.918-3.175,7.096-7.094,7.096h-34.082c-3.918,0-7.096-3.177-7.096-7.096V224.234
 c0-3.918,3.177-7.096,7.096-7.096h34.082c3.918,0,7.094,3.177,7.094,7.096v12.009c8.054-12.085,20.023-21.416,45.502-21.416
 c56.425,0,56.105,52.717,56.105,81.686v66.627H371.773z"/>
<path style="fill:#D1D1D1;" d="M376.023,109.468H255.427v107.67h7.647c3.918,0,7.094,3.177,7.094,7.096v12.009
 c8.054-12.085,20.023-21.416,45.503-21.416c56.425,0,56.105,52.717,56.105,81.686v66.625c0,3.918-3.175,7.096-7.09,7.096h-35.242
 c-3.915,0-7.092-3.177-7.092-7.096v-64.574c0-9.63,2.826-42.21-25.172-42.21c-21.719,0-26.124,22.3-27.008,32.304v74.478
 c0,3.918-3.175,7.096-7.094,7.096h-7.647v32.301h120.596c14.639,0,26.51-11.871,26.51-26.51V135.978
 C402.533,121.335,390.662,109.468,376.023,109.468z"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Set the width and height of the <svg> element to 16px

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) in the comments - you can set the width and height attributes of the SVG node and you will achieve the desired result.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="16" height="16"
  viewBox="0 0 512.002 512.002" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512.002 512.002;" xml:space="preserve">
<circle style="fill:#4376B1;" cx="256.001" cy="256" r="256"/>
<path style="fill:#336699;" d="M511.016,233.634L394.729,117.198c-71.035,9.237-145.27,7.859-216.305,9.511
 c-29.306,0-58.613,13.791-53.441,46.545c10.343,65.508,15.515,129.293,3.448,196.525c-1.9,8.545-5.897,17.089-11.117,25.059
 L233.48,511.005c7.421,0.646,14.929,0.996,22.519,0.996c141.384,0,256-114.616,256-256
 C512.001,248.461,511.656,241.005,511.016,233.634z"/>
<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M376.023,109.468H135.979c-14.643,0-26.51,11.867-26.51,26.51V376.02
 c0,14.639,11.867,26.51,26.51,26.51h240.042c14.639,0,26.51-11.871,26.51-26.51V135.978
 C402.533,121.335,390.662,109.468,376.023,109.468L376.023,109.468z M200.155,362.517c0,4.263-3.453,7.716-7.716,7.716h-32.837
 c-4.263,0-7.716-3.455-7.716-7.716V224.856c0-4.263,3.455-7.716,7.716-7.716h32.839c4.263,0,7.716,3.455,7.716,7.716v137.661
 H200.155z M176.02,204.162c-17.23,0-31.196-13.969-31.196-31.201c0-17.229,13.965-31.196,31.196-31.196
 c17.232,0,31.198,13.969,31.198,31.196C207.218,190.195,193.251,204.162,176.02,204.162L176.02,204.162z M371.773,363.139
 c0,3.918-3.175,7.096-7.09,7.096h-35.242c-3.915,0-7.092-3.177-7.092-7.096v-64.574c0-9.63,2.826-42.21-25.172-42.21
 c-21.719,0-26.124,22.3-27.008,32.304v74.478c0,3.918-3.175,7.096-7.094,7.096h-34.082c-3.918,0-7.096-3.177-7.096-7.096V224.234
 c0-3.918,3.177-7.096,7.096-7.096h34.082c3.918,0,7.094,3.177,7.094,7.096v12.009c8.054-12.085,20.023-21.416,45.502-21.416
 c56.425,0,56.105,52.717,56.105,81.686v66.627H371.773z"/>
<path style="fill:#D1D1D1;" d="M376.023,109.468H255.427v107.67h7.647c3.918,0,7.094,3.177,7.094,7.096v12.009
 c8.054-12.085,20.023-21.416,45.503-21.416c56.425,0,56.105,52.717,56.105,81.686v66.625c0,3.918-3.175,7.096-7.09,7.096h-35.242
 c-3.915,0-7.092-3.177-7.092-7.096v-64.574c0-9.63,2.826-42.21-25.172-42.21c-21.719,0-26.124,22.3-27.008,32.304v74.478
 c0,3.918-3.175,7.096-7.094,7.096h-7.647v32.301h120.596c14.639,0,26.51-11.871,26.51-26.51V135.978
 C402.533,121.335,390.662,109.468,376.023,109.468z"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="16px" height="16px">.....</svg>`

set fixed width and height for svg tag...